# Plotting (beta) curves in R

Tags: r

I have used the following code to plot a beta curve:

```
p <- seq(0, 1, length=100)
plot(p, dbeta(p, 5, 7), ylab="density", type="l", col=4)
```

I wanted to plot two curves on the same graph and so repeated the second line using different numerical values in place of the 5 and 7. This resulted in the second curve being printed on a different graph (i.e. I got two separate graphs). Could anyone explain how to get both curves on the same graph?

Comment: Instead of `plot`, use `?lines` And if you have a matrix of values, checkout `?matplot`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

p= as.data.frame(seq(0,6,length=100))

ggplot(p) +
  stat_function(fun = function(p) dbeta(p, 5, 7), color = "red", size = 1) +
  xlab("beta curve")
```